# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-P

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, android-9.0-pie

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-P

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.google.codelabs.mdc.java.shrine"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
     }

    dependencies {
        api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
        implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

Comment: add your gradle file

Comment: I've added that gradle code and the solution below.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Step 1: Open Preferences or Settings in Android studio. Select Android SDK options and Install Android API 28 as selected below.

[image: install]

Step 2: There's a problem with compileSdkVersion as you have to change it from 'android-P' to 28.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

And Build project. That's it.

Answer (score 7):

To fully test your app's compatibility with Android P and begin using new APIs, open your module-level build.gradle file and update the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion as shown here:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    ...
}
```

[Set Up the Android P SDK](https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk)

Answer (score 2):

**Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-R**

put this code in `android/build.gradle` at the end

```
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"

    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')

    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to update the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 30 resolves the problem[image: SDK Version Change]

Answer (score 0):

Problem: **Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-27**

Solution:

- Just change `compileSdkVersion` to 30, and `targetSdkVersion` to 30 and click on sync. The system will download some files and done. (you want an internet connection for this)

```
android {
 compileSdkVersion 30
 defaultConfig {
       targetSdkVersion 30
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, Can you tell me the name of file which we have to modify?