# Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-27

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I'm taking an Android course and I'm supposed to review my peer's apps.

The app I'm looking at now fails to build with the error, "Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-27".

I have looked at the answer for [Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183581/failed-to-find-platform-sdk-with-path-platformsandroid-p), but the menus that are displayed don't match the menus in the version of Android Studio I am using (AS 3.3 for Windows).

I'm hoping that someone can tell me how to add Android Platform 27 to my version of Android Studio.

Thanks.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update#sdk-manager Follow the link and scroll to the section "Update your tools with the SDK Manager". You will see the menu for version 3.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to Tools > SDK Manager and download API level 28. You may also have to change the `'android-27'` text to simply `27` in the app-level build.gradle file. You should really post the app-level build.gradle file so we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Open the android build.gradle file of your project from backend (file structure) and change "compileSdkVersion 27" property to "compileSdkVersion 29" or the sdk version you are using.