# flutter Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-

Tags: android, flutter

I am trying to run a flutter app on Android studio. It throws error

```
flutter Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-R
```

My app build.gradle is

```
buildscript {
 ...


    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.inspireui.fluxstore"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
        resConfigs "en"
    }


    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android") && project.property("android").compileSdkVersion.equals("android-R")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 30
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Have tried below solution
[Failed to find Platform SDK with path: platforms;android-P](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183581/failed-to-find-platform-sdk-with-path-platformsandroid-p)